# Update a Map in groovy spock framework

Tags: groovy, spock

I have the below spock specification and want to update the map from data table.  Can some body help achieve this

```
def "groovy map update"() {                                                   
        setup: "step1"                                                            

        Map json = [                                                              
                user :[                                                           
                        name : 'ABC'                                              
                ]]                                                                

        when: "step2"                                                             

        println ('Before modification:')                                          
        println (json)                                                            

        then: "step3"                                                             

        json.with {                                                               
            //user.name = value // this one works                                 
            (field) = value   // this one does not work                           
        }                                                                         

        println ('After modification:')                                           
        println (json)                                                            

        where:                                                                    
        field                               | value                               
        'user.name'                         | 'XYZ'                               

    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example, that shows the actual test or what you are after? This right now looks like you want to change a nested map value and it's obfuscated by wrapping it in a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `then` section is intended for asserts and not for updates etc. So you have to update the map in the `when` section and then test the result in the `then` section. For example like this:

```
def "groovy map update"() {
    setup: 'create json'
    Map json = [user: [name: 'ABC']]

    when: 'update it'
    def target = json
    for (node in path - path.last()) {
        target = target[node]
    }
    target[path.last()] = value

    then: 'check the assignment'
    json.user.name == value

    where:
    path             | value
    ['user', 'name'] | 'XYZ'
}
```

One way how to update nested `Map` value can be by using list of path nodes instead of field notation and then iterate over them to obtain the last `Map` instance and set the value there:

```
def target = json
for (node in path - path.last()) {
    target = target[node]
}
target[path.last()] = value
```

Comment: I think OP want to update "by path" (e.g. first `user` then `name`)

Comment: @cfrick yes, you are right - I updated the answer accordingly, thanks for notifying me

Comment: I'm more attracted to an reduce/inject - but nice solution +1

Comment: Perfect! got what  I need. Could you please clarify how the original 'json' map gets updated although we are modifying the 'target' map

Comment: The original `json` map is updated because it is an object containing other objects and `traget` is only reference on them which is going from root to leaf. So when you are updating the `target` you are also updating sub-object in the `json` object.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution is correct, I just want to show an alternative doing the same in a slightly different way, assuming you want to stick with the dotted notation for `field` in your `where:` block. I just added two more test cases in order to make sure it works as expected.

```groovy
@Unroll
def "set #field to #value"() {
  setup: 'create json'
  Map json = [user: [name: 'ABC', address: [street: '21 Main St', zip: '12345', city: 'Hometown']]]

  when: 'update it'
  def subMap = json
  field.split("[.]").each {
    if (subMap[it] instanceof Map)
      subMap = subMap[it]
    else
      subMap[it] = value
  }
  println json

  then: 'check the assignment'
  json.newField == value ||
    json.user.name == value ||
    json.user.address.zip == value

  where:
  field              | value
  'newField'         | 'dummy'
  'user.name'        | 'XYZ'
  'user.address.zip' | '98765'
}
```

---

**Update:** If you want to save a few lines of code you can also use a fold (or reduce or accumulate) operation via `inject(..)` as described [here](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-inject-method.html)

```groovy
@Unroll
def "set #field to #value"() {
  setup: 'create json'
  Map json = [user: [name: 'ABC', address: [street: '21 Main St', zip: '12345', city: 'Hometown']]]

  when: 'update it'
  field.split("[.]").inject(json) { subMap, key ->
    subMap[key] instanceof Map ? subMap[key] : subMap.put(key, value)
  }
  println json

  then: 'check the assignment'
  json.newField == value ||
    json.user.name == value ||
    json.user.address.zip == value

  where:
  field              | value
  'newField'         | 'dummy'
  'user.name'        | 'XYZ'
  'user.address.zip' | '98765'
}
```

Whether you find that readable or not may depend on your familiarity with topics like functional programming in general or map/reduce in particular. The charm here in addition to brevity is that we no longer need a local variable outside of our closure but we just inject (hence the method name) the result of iteration n to iteration n+1.

BTW, as a nice side effect `inject(..)` as I am using it here returns the previous value of the value you set or overwrite. Just add `println` in front of `field.split("[.]").inject(json) ...` in order to see it.

---

**Update 2:** Please note that both variants only work if there is no existing field value of type `Map` in the target field because of the `instanceof Map` check heuristics in my code. I.e. these two cases would not work:

```groovy
    'user.address'            | [street: '23 Test Blvd', zip: '33333', city: 'Somewhere']
    'user.address'            | '23 Test Blvd, 33333 Somewhere'
```

This one would work, though, because there is no preexisting value:

```groovy
    'user.alternativeAddress' | [street: '23 Test Blvd', zip: '33333', city: 'Somewhere']
```

Comment: Update: I added a variant using `inject(..)` just for the pleasure of playing around with it.

Comment: Update 2: I am explaining the limitations of the approach with `instanceof Map` check.